# Updating datagridview from main form to another form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 forms. In the main form there is datagridview and 2 buttons (add button and update button). When the user click the update button I want to update datagridview from main form to another form. But I don't know how to do it. Can I ask for the code?

Comment: Please specify how you are loading the DataGridView and in regards to the child form, is it being shown modally or not. More details the better responses will come your way.

Comment: I am using ms access

Answer (score 0):

Just call an action from another form:

```
**AnotherForm**.DataGridView1.*Thecodeyouwant*
```

Change **AnotherForm** to the name of the form wich is with the DataGridView and *Thecodeyouwant* to the update code.